# redux-toolkitで、あるstateのプロパティの変更を基にそのstateの別プロパティを変更することは可能かどうか

Tags: reactjs, redux

現在Reactで開発をし、redux-toolkitでstate管理をしています。

そこで質問なのですが、例えば下記のようなsliceがあったとします。
sliceとしては、user毎に異なるitemsを持っているため、userが変わればitemsも変わるようにstateを変更したいと考えています。（storeは省略しています）

**testslice.js**

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
    user:{id:"",name:""},
    items: []    
}

//sliceの作成 
const testSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'test', 
    initialState, 
    reducers: {
        changeUser(state, action) { 
            state.user = { ...action.payload };
        },
        renewItems(state, action) {
            state.items = [...action.payload];
        }
    },
})

export const {changeUser, renewItems} = testSlice.actions;
export const selectTest=(state =>state.test);
export default testSlice.reducer;
```

次に実際にreducersで定義したactionをdispatchしようとしているコンポーネントは下記になります。
ボタンをクリックするとchangeUserでuserが変わり、その変わったuserを基にItemsを更新するというactionを通知しようとしています。（引数は省略しています）

**TestPage.jsx**

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { changeUser, renewItems} from '../slice/testSlice';
import { Button } from '@mui/material';
import React from 'react';
import { selectTest } from '../slice/testSlice';
import store from '../store';


export const TestPage = () => {
    const getTest = useSelector(selectTest);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const testPach = () => {
        dispatch(changeUser());
        dispatch(renewItems());
    };
    console.log(store.getState());

    return (
        <>
            <div>{getTest.user.name}</div>
            <Button variant="contained" onClick={() => testPach()}>testSlice用</Button>
        </>
    );
};
```

上記のように、あるコンポーネントでボタンがクリックされたことをトリガーとして、あるstateのプロパティの変更を基に、そのstateの別のプロパティを更新しようとするのはredux-toolkitの仕様としてNGでしょうか？(またはredux単体でNGかもしれませんが…）

どなたかご存じの方がいらっしゃいましたらご教授お願いします。